# push notification- app update

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification

We have one push enabled app in app store and we would like to release an update. Would the same set of certificates (SSL) work or do we need to update them? Does apple have this in documentation?
Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to update them. You just need to distinguish between sandbox and production certificates for an application. And I think you'd need to renew them after one year, but not sure about this.